# How to determine if set is open

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I need help in determining if this set is open, closed, compact, connected, and path-connected. I can't fully determine if it's open or closed, and if I could determine that, I could easily get other ones correct. Set is $A = \{ (x, y) \in R^2 \,|\, x \ge 0, {1\over1+e^{-x}} \le y \le 1 \}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! This is not always 100% guaranteed, but usually set definitions like these with all inequalities being large tend to be closed, and definitions with all inequalities being strict would tend to be open. Hint: try picking a sequence $((x_n, y_n))_n$ in $A$ converging to some $(x,y)$ and try showing that $(x,y)$ belongs in $A$.

Comment: It seems that you're expecting us to do your job... Which is not the target of this website! So please update your question with what you have tried and what issues you're facing to answer the questions. Thanks. Also when you say *...I could determine that, I could easily get other ones correct....*, you're too optimistic as compactness and connectedness may be more difficult points than openness or closeness.

Comment: @NDB You probably shouldn't answer the question in that much detail in the comments. You could turn this into an answer I guess though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set is closed under limits, thus it is closed.
In fact, if we take a sequence of points $\{(x_i,y_i)\}_{i=1,2,\dots} \subset A$ which converges to $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, then it holds $x_i\geq 0 \ \forall \ i$, which clearly implies $x \geq 0$. In the same way, $y_i \leq 1 \ \forall \ i \implies y\leq 1$.

On the other side, let's denote with $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$. If $y_i \geq \frac{1}{1+e^{-x_i}}$, since $f$ is continuous, $\lim\limits_{i \to\infty}f(x_i) = f(x)$ and then:
$$y_i \geq f(x_i) \ \forall \ i \implies y=\lim\limits_{i\to\infty} y_i \geq \lim\limits_{i\to\infty} f(x_i)=f(x) \ ,$$
which means that $(x,y)\in A$.

Regarding the other questions, some suggestions:

-Open: Is it complementary set closed? Try to use limits

-Compact: Recall that in euclidean topology compact $\iff$ closed and bounded, so...

-Path-connected: try to think how to make an easy path (for instance, go to the border $y=1/(1+e^{-x})$, go through it and then go to the destination point. This is a very rough idea

-Connected: if you show that it is path-connected it is also connected